# Why is Cassandra ignoring my schema modifications?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm pretty new to Cassandra.  I've had a single-node cluster running for a few days with no problems but today it started ignoring some of my CQL commands.  `SELECT`s work fine but if I run `DROP TABLE foo;` from cqlsh then nothing happens.  After a half-second pause it returns me to the prompt but the table wasn't dropped.  The same goes for creating an index using `CREATE INDEX`.

I'm running in a virtual machine, using the Cassandra distribution from OpenStax on Ubuntu 12.04.

I checked the Cassandra logs and I definitely get output when I run a CREATE INDEX, but no apparent errors:

```
 CREATE INDEX number_uri_index ON numbers (number);
```

Produces:

```
 INFO [MigrationStage:1] 2012-07-25 14:25:59,120 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 643) Enqueuing flush of Memtable-schema_columnfamilies@15955724(1212/1515 serialized/live bytes, 20 ops)
 INFO [FlushWriter:5] 2012-07-25 14:25:59,122 Memtable.java (line 266) Writing Memtable-schema_columnfamilies@15955724(1212/1515 serialized/live bytes, 20 ops)
 INFO [FlushWriter:5] 2012-07-25 14:25:59,139 Memtable.java (line 307) Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-hd-50-Data.db (1267 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=140485087964, position=8551)
 INFO [MigrationStage:1] 2012-07-25 14:25:59,141 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 643) Enqueuing flush of Memtable-schema_columns@7576227(320/400 serialized/live bytes, 5 ops)
 INFO [FlushWriter:5] 2012-07-25 14:25:59,141 Memtable.java (line 266) Writing Memtable-schema_columns@7576227(320/400 serialized/live bytes, 5 ops)
 INFO [FlushWriter:5] 2012-07-25 14:25:59,172 Memtable.java (line 307) Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-hd-46-Data.db (367 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=140485087964, position=8551)
```

Comment: Can you try using cassandra-cli and drop the same column family and see what happens?

Comment: Sorry, I've now deleted the whole data dir and started over.  I did try using CQL 2 and 3 and CQL via the python bindings.  All failed the same way.

Comment: One of my colleagues just hit the same problem but for her it worked if she used cqlsh at version 2 instead of 3.  If it happens again we'll try cassandra-cli

Comment: Ok, she hit the issue again and tried cassandra-cli and she can drop both column families and the keyspace.

Comment: @Fasaxc that issue sounds like a case sensitivity problem. CQL 2 is case-preserving, but CQL 3 downcases everything by default (so if you have a preexisting CF or KS with capital letters in its name, you have to double-quote that name in CQL 3).

Comment: @Fasaxc that is, your colleague's problem sounds like that. Yours doesn't, since cqlsh should be giving errors if the DROP or CREATE INDEX failed.

Comment: I have no idea what Cassandra release "OpenStax on Ubuntu 12.04" corresponds to.  Can you try the official Cassandra 1.1.2 release from http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DebianPackaging ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem here in a 3 nodes setup. Solved doing the same modification on a second node.
Investiganting CASSANDRA jira we discovered that it could be related with the way timestamps are managed by schema related commands and it should be fixed in 1.1.3:

[CASSANDRA-4461](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4461)
[CASSANDRA-4432](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4432)

Comment: That seems to match my symptoms exactly.

Comment: We had the same issues and I can confirm cassanda 1.1.3 fixed them